# 作りながら学ぶreact入門　〜インストール手順 Mac編〜　でエラー

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-jsx, reactive-programming, react-router-dom

https://github.com/yuumi3/react_book/blob/master/docs/install_mac.md を参考に進めたところ、npm start　でエラーが発生してしまいます。

```
> hello_react@1.0.0 start
> webpack serve

[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'publicPath'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
```

環境は Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
ディレクトリ構造は参考githubと同じです。

./webpack.congig.jsの中身はこんな感じ。

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/js',
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
    devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname + '/public',
    port: 8080,
    publicPath: '/js/'
  },
  devtool: "eval-source-map",
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      enforce: "pre",
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: "eslint-loader"
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader","css-loader"]
    }, {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
     }]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[こちら](https://github.com/yuumi3/react_book/blob/master/projects/hello_react/package.json#L32) を見ると `"^3.11.2"` が指定されていますので、`package.json`を同じように書き換えた上で

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

次のコマンドを実行すれば動作するでしょう。

```
npm install
npm start
```

---

[リファレンス](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) から辿れる[移行ガイド](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/migration-v4.md)にありますが、エラーメッセージに出ている `publicPath` の設定書式はバージョン `3` のものです。
[説明](https://github.com/yuumi3/react_book/blob/master/docs/install_mac.md#2-7-npm%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)通りコマンドを実行すると(発刊当時の2017年とは異なり)2021年現在では現行バージョンである `4` がインストールされますので、ダウングレードする必要があります。